# apply different theme to action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am trying to apply a theme to my action bar which will change the background color. However when I do this the whole background of the application changes...

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">140dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00ff00</item>
</style>
```

Does anyone know how I can apply a separate theme to the action bar?

Thanks.

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">140dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar LAYOUT -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like this:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar" >
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    </style>
```

This is how you can change the background:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
       <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/black</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying no resource found for the Widget.ActionBar?

Comment: Oh sorry, it should have been android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar. I edited my answer

Comment: thanks your correction worked, however I am still having an issue changing the background color..As a test I am trying to set the action bar background to white and the application background to black but it is not working, I added my code to my question. Any idea why?